# Why do I get the error "Cannot create a DbSet for 'IdentityUserClaim<string>'" when I log into the asp.net core using Identity?

Tags: asp.net-core, authentication, .net-core, asp.net-identity

i am using "AddIdentityCore" insted of "AddDefaultIdentity"  here is my code

```cs
builder.Services.AddIdentityCore<AppUser>(options =>
{
     options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true;
     options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedEmail = true;
     options.Password.RequiredLength = 6;
     options.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
     options.Password.RequireDigit = false;
     options.Password.RequireLowercase = false;
     options.Password.RequireUppercase = false;
     options.User.RequireUniqueEmail = true;
}).AddEntityFrameworkStores<VincheckDbContext>().AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

I configure my DbContext

```
 public class VincheckDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public VincheckDbContext()
        {
        }
        public VincheckDbContext(DbContextOptions<VincheckDbContext> options) : base(options)
        { }
        public DbSet<AppUserLogin> AppUserLogins { get; set; }
        public DbSet<AppUserToken> AppUserTokens { get; set; }
        public DbSet<AppUserClaim> AppUserClaims { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(builder);
            builder.Entity<AppUser>(x =>
            {
                // A concurrency token for use with the optimistic concurrency checking
                x.Property(u => u.ConcurrencyStamp).IsConcurrencyToken();
                // Limit the size of columns to use efficient database types
                x.Property(u => u.Email).HasMaxLength(128);
                x.Property(u => u.NormalizedEmail).HasMaxLength(128);
                x.Property(u => u.UserName).HasMaxLength(128);
                x.Property(u => u.NormalizedUserName).HasMaxLength(128);
                x.Ignore(u => u.PhoneNumber);
                x.Ignore(u => u.PhoneNumberConfirmed);

                //x.Ignore(u => u.TwoFactorEnabled);

                // Each User can have many UserClaims
                x.HasMany(e => e.UserClaims)
                    .WithOne(e => e.AppUser)
                    .HasForeignKey(uc => uc.UserId)
                    .IsRequired();

                // Each User can have many UserLogins
                x.HasMany(e => e.UserLogins)
                    .WithOne(e => e.AppUser)
                    .HasForeignKey(ul => ul.UserId)
                    .IsRequired();

                // Each User can have many UserTokens
                x.HasMany(e => e.UserTokens)
                    .WithOne(e => e.AppUser)
                    .HasForeignKey(ut => ut.UserId)
                    .IsRequired();
            });
            builder.Entity<AppUserClaim>(b =>
            {
                // Primary key
                b.HasKey(uc => uc.Id);
            });
            builder.Entity<AppUserLogin>(b =>
            {
                // Composite primary key consisting of the LoginProvider and the key to use
                // with that provider
                b.HasKey(l => new { l.LoginProvider, l.ProviderKey });

                // Limit the size of the composite key columns due to common DB restrictions
                b.Property(l => l.LoginProvider).HasMaxLength(128);
                b.Property(l => l.ProviderKey).HasMaxLength(128);
            });
            builder.Entity<AppUserToken>(b =>
            {
                // Composite primary key consisting of the UserId, LoginProvider and Name
                b.HasKey(t => new { t.UserId, t.LoginProvider, t.Name });

                // Limit the size of the composite key columns due to common DB restrictions
                b.Property(t => t.LoginProvider).HasMaxLength(128);
                b.Property(t => t.Name).HasMaxLength(128);
            });
        }
    }
```

and this is my IdentityUser entity and I have also configured my relations and navigation properties with other entities

```
 public class AppUser :IdentityUser<string>
    {
        public AppUser()
        {

        }
        public AppUser(string userName)
        {

        }
        public AppUser(List<AppUserToken> userTokens, List<AppUserLogin> userLogins, List<AppUserClaim> userClaims)
        {
            UserTokens = userTokens;
            UserLogins = userLogins;
            UserClaims = userClaims;
        }

        public List<AppUserToken> UserTokens { get; set; }
        public List<AppUserLogin> UserLogins { get; set; }  
        public List<AppUserClaim> UserClaims { get; set; }  
    }
```

I advance my code by putting a breakpoint in this code when I log in, `var result = wait _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(Input.Email, Input.Password, Input.RememberMe, false);` it gives an error here and I get the error in the picture below

Login code

```
 public class LoginModel : PageModel
    {
        private readonly SignInManager<AppUser> _signInManager;
        private readonly UserManager<AppUser> _userManager;

        public LoginModel(SignInManager<AppUser> signInManager, UserManager<AppUser> userManager)
        {
            _signInManager = signInManager;
            _userManager = userManager;
        }


        [BindProperty]
        public InputModel Input { get; set; }


        public IList<AuthenticationScheme> ExternalLogins { get; set; }


        public string ReturnUrl { get; set; }


        [TempData]
        public string ErrorMessage { get; set; }


        public class InputModel
        {
            [Required]
            [EmailAddress]
            public string Email { get; set; }

            [Required]
            [DataType(DataType.Password)]
            public string Password { get; set; }

            [Display(Name = "Remember me?")]
            public bool RememberMe { get; set; }
        }

        public async Task OnGetAsync(string returnUrl = null)
        {
            returnUrl ??= Url.Content("~/");
            await HttpContext.SignOutAsync(IdentityConstants.ExternalScheme);
            ExternalLogins = (await _signInManager.GetExternalAuthenticationSchemesAsync()).ToList();
            ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
        }

        public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync(string returnUrl = null)
        {
            returnUrl ??= Url.Content("~/");

            ExternalLogins = (await _signInManager.GetExternalAuthenticationSchemesAsync()).ToList();

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {

                var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(Input.Email, Input.Password, Input.RememberMe, false);
                if (result.Succeeded)
                {
                    _logger.LogInformation("User logged in.");
                    return LocalRedirect(returnUrl);
                }
                else
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Invalid login attempt.");
                    return Page();
                }
            }

            return Page();
        }
    }
```

I am getting this error
[image: Error]

Answer (score 0):

Your `VincheckDbContext` is NOT inherited from `DbContext` but instead it should be inherited from `IdentityDbContext<AppUser>`.  If you are using a DbContext not derived.from IdentityDbContext, then you could see this error: as [this](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/12511) and [this](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/5793).

try to add below code in your VincheckDbContext:

```
public DbSet<IdentityUserClaim<string>> IdentityUserClaim { get; set; }  
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder Builder)
        {   Builder.Entity<IdentityUserClaim<string>>().HasKey(p => new { p.Id });
         
        }
```